# Is there a way to chdir() into a directory where only the beginning of the directory name is known?

Tags: c

So, basically, I have a program that forks off a child process and creates a directory with the name + the child processes ID. This is done in another part of the code.

So, lets say the user names the directory "TestDir#". It will be TestDir12342 or something similar in the end.

So, later on, the user could enter a search term for that directory by typing in TestDir#. I want to lope off the "#", and have chdir() search for a directory that begins with that name, "TestDir". I don't have to worry about repeat files or similarly named files for this program.

Does anyone know a simple way to do this with chdir()? I have tried many different test code, but I am at a lose.

I have also attempted to store the child process ID in the parent process, but for some reason I can never get them to match. I am aware that fork() gives the child process ID in return to the parent. Yet, for some reason, the program refuses to make them match.

So, I am trying this as a workaround (searching the beginning part of the file name). Thanks for any assistance if someone knows of a way to do this.

Comment: I think you will have to manually search for prefix matches using `strncmp` on the files in the parent directory.

Comment: Debugging the code which fails to keep the process ID seems appropriate. I think making that part of this question would be, too. It would (in my opinion) still be a clear and single question on coding. So consider making a [mcve] which shows both parts. Answers could be based on finding the ID problem or improving the attempts on directory names you have. In case this (my comment) gets contradicted, make a second question.

Comment: In Linux use [`glob`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) to find the paths you are interested in.

Comment: Unless you post your code and show us how your are calling `fork` and attempting to store the child `PID`, there isn't much we can do to help solve your problem.

Comment: @slevy1: you are confusing `chdir` the function with `chdir` the shell builtin command, misunderstanding who performs glob expansion (=the shell, not the kernel when you perform syscalls), and not considering the fact that, even if you spawn a shell just to do a `chdir` (ARGH why would you do that?), it would be useless anyway, since the current directory is a per-process property, so the fact that the spawned process changed directory wouldn't impact your program the slightest.

Comment: _I have tried many different test code_... Well, where's that code?  Do we have to guess the mistake you have commited?

Answer (score 2):

`readdir` can be used to get the entries of the directory.

The following `searchFirstDir` finds the first prefix-matched directory. (tested in Ubuntu Linux)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int searchFirstDir(const char *workingDir, const char *prefix, char *resultBuffer, int bufferLen)
{
    DIR *pDir = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    // opendir
    {
        pDir = opendir(workingDir);
        if (pDir == NULL) {
            perror("ERROR: opendir");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // readdir
    {
        int ret;
        struct dirent *pEntry;
        struct dirent *result;
        int prefixLen = strlen(prefix);

        // refer: man readdir (in Linux)
        {
            long name_max = pathconf(workingDir, _PC_NAME_MAX);
            if (name_max == -1)         /* Limit not defined, or error */
                name_max = 255;         /* Take a guess */
            size_t len = offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + name_max + 1;
            pEntry = malloc(len);
        }

        do {
            ret = readdir_r(pDir, pEntry, &result);
            if (ret) {
                perror("ERROR: readdir_r");
                break;
            }

            if (pEntry->d_type == DT_DIR && strncmp(pEntry->d_name, prefix, prefixLen) == 0) {
                strncpy(resultBuffer, pEntry->d_name, bufferLen);
                found++;
                break;
            }
        } while(ret == 0 && result != NULL);

        free(pEntry);
    }

    // closedir
    closedir(pDir);

    return found > 0 ? 0 : -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    char resultBuffer[255];

    int ret = searchFirstDir("workingdirectory", "TestDir", resultBuffer, 255);
    if (ret == 0) {
        printf("First matched directory: %s\n", resultBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful, `strncpy` doesn't always nul-terminate the target string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to perform the requested type of chdir taking advantage of globbing, i.e. filename expansion using a wildcard of "*", as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <glob.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Convert a wildcard pattern into a list of blank-separated
   filenames which match the wildcard.  */

char * glob_pattern(char *wildcard)
{
  char *gfilename;
  size_t cnt, length;
  glob_t glob_results;
  char **p;

  glob(wildcard, GLOB_NOCHECK, 0, &glob_results);

  /* How much space do we need?  */
  for (p = glob_results.gl_pathv, cnt = glob_results.gl_pathc;
       cnt; p++, cnt--)
    length += strlen(*p) + 1;

  /* Allocate the space and generate the list.  */
  gfilename = (char *) calloc(length, sizeof(char));
  for (p = glob_results.gl_pathv, cnt = glob_results.gl_pathc;
       cnt; p++, cnt--)
    {
      strcat(gfilename, *p);
      if (cnt > 1)
        strcat(gfilename, " ");
    }

  globfree(&glob_results);
  return gfilename;
}

int main() {
   char *directory;
   int ret;


   directory = glob_pattern("te*");

   ret = chdir (directory);
   printf("Result of chdir: %d\n",ret);
}
```

Note: The "globbing" portion of the code comes from [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_426.html)

Linux has a glob utility so if you wish to do the same in C, you have to write the code yourself as this example portrays.  When the program finishes however you will be back in the directory you originally used to run this script.  When the code does a successful directory change, the return result is zero. Note, this code executed in a directory containing a subdirectory named "test".